# how to correct type declaration for generic interface

Tags: typescript

Simple function which builds tree structure.

```js
interface CommonItem {
  id: string
  parent: string | null
}

interface CommonTreeItem {
  children: CommonTreeItem[]
}

export const buildTree = <Item extends CommonItem, TreeItem extends CommonTreeItem & Item>(
  data: Item[]
): TreeItem[] => {
  const root: TreeItem[] = []
  const dataMap = new Map<string, TreeItem>()

  for (const item of data) {
    dataMap.set(item.id, {...item, children: []})
    //                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //                   TS2345: Argument of type 'Item & { children: never[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TreeItem'.
  }

  for (const originalItem of data) {
    if (originalItem.parent) {
      const parentItem = dataMap.get(originalItem.parent)
      const item = <TreeItem>dataMap.get(originalItem.id)
      if (parentItem) {
        parentItem.children.push(item)
      }
    } else {
      root.push(
        <TreeItem>dataMap.get(originalItem.id)
      )
    }
  }

  return root
}
```

I don't understand why linter fails.
I tried create types which has Item as generic but it fails.
May be need to build TreeItem by different way!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error message I'm seeing is:

```
Argument of type 'Item & { children: never[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TreeItem'.
  'Item & { children: never[]; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TreeItem', but 'TreeItem' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'CommonTreeItem & CommonItem'.ts(2345)
```

This has to do with how `TreeItem extends CommonTreeItem & Item` only says that the resulting type should contain `id`, `parent` and `children`, but could contain more fields. Type checking on `Map#set` is more strict, and checks that the item being set matches the type exactly (cannot contain additional fields)

You can get around this error by instead defining `TreeItem` more concretely instead of using an `extends` as follows:

```js
const buildTree = <Item extends CommonItem>(data: Item[]) => {
  type TreeItem = CommonTreeItem & Item
  const root: TreeItem[] = []
  const dataMap = new Map<string, TreeItem>()

  for (const item of data) {
    dataMap.set(item.id, { ...item, children: [] })
  }

  for (const originalItem of data) {
    if (originalItem.parent) {
      const parentItem = dataMap.get(originalItem.parent)
      const item = <TreeItem>dataMap.get(originalItem.id)
      if (parentItem) {
        parentItem.children.push(item)
      }
    } else {
      root.push(<TreeItem>dataMap.get(originalItem.id))
    }
  }

  return root
}
```

You'll see that we've removed the return type annotation, but the function's type should get inferred correctly as

```js
const buildTree: <Item extends CommonItem>(data: Item[]) => TreeItem[]
```

See also

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks
- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/typescript-excess-property-checks-6ffe5584f450